# Unwanted location added expo

Tags: android, react-native, expo, location, android-permissions

I tried to publish my application on Google Play Console, and I have three permissions that I never added to my projects. I tried everything and I looked everywhere but I can't figure this out.

- android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
- android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
- android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION

Here is the package.json, I suspect that a package adds this but I looked in the node_modules and I don't find anything.

I checked google-services as well, and added to remove with tools:node="remove" but it doesn't change anything, google play console still detects those permissions.

Is there someone that had this issue?

package.json :

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^15.2.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/in-app-messaging": "^15.4.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^15.4.0",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "0.2.6",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.2.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "expo": "^45.0.0",
    "expo-application": "~4.1.0",
    "expo-constants": "~13.1.1",
    "expo-image-picker": "~13.1.1",
    "expo-in-app-purchases": "^13.1.0",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.15.4",
    "expo-skeleton-loader": "^1.1.3",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.15.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.13.3",
    "firebase": "9.6.11",
    "formik": "2.1.4",
    "patch-package": "^6.4.7",
    "postinstall-postinstall": "^2.1.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-actionsheet": "^2.4.2",
    "react-native-animated-progress": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "^4.0.4",
    "react-native-dialog": "^9.2.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.2.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.4",
    "react-native-pager-view": "^5.4.25",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.8.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.9",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.11.1",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.7",
    "yup": "0.27.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.9.0",
    "babel-preset-expo": "~9.1.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "picpick"
}
```

app.config.js :

```
import 'dotenv/config';

export default {
  expo: {
    plugins: [
      "@react-native-firebase/app"
    ],
    name: 'test',
    slug: 'test',
    privacy: 'public',
    platforms: ['ios', 'android'],
    version: '1.0.0',
    orientation: 'portrait',
    icon: './assets/flame.png',
    splash: {
      image: './assets/splash.png',
      resizeMode: 'contain',
      backgroundColor: '#fff'
    },
    updates: {
      fallbackToCacheTimeout: 0
    },
    assetBundlePatterns: ['**/*'],
    ios: {
      supportsTablet: true,
      googleServicesFile: "./google-services.json"
    },
    android: {
      package: "com.test",
      versionCode: 6,
      googleServicesFile: "./google-services.json"},
    web: {
      config: {
        firebase: {
          apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
          authDomain: process.env.AUTH_DOMAIN,
          projectId: process.env.PROJECT_ID,
          storageBucket: process.env.STORAGE_BUCKET,
          messagingSenderId: process.env.MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
          appId: process.env.APP_ID,
          measurementId: process.env.MEASUREMENT_ID
        }
      }
    },
    extra: {
      apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
      authDomain: process.env.AUTH_DOMAIN,
      projectId: process.env.PROJECT_ID,
      storageBucket: process.env.STORAGE_BUCKET,
      messagingSenderId: process.env.MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
      appId: process.env.APP_ID,
      measurementId: process.env.MEASUREMENT_ID
    }
  }
};
```

AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.pixpix" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
  <queries>
    <intent>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
      <data android:scheme="https"/>
    </intent>
  </queries>
  <application android:name=".MainApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:allowBackup="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.ENABLED" android:value="true"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_RELEASE_CHANNEL" android:value="default"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_SDK_VERSION" android:value="45.0.0"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_CHECK_ON_LAUNCH" android:value="ALWAYS"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_LAUNCH_WAIT_MS" android:value="0"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATE_URL" android:value="https://exp.host/@user/test"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen" android:exported="true" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="com.pixpix"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" android:exported="false"/>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Can you provide us with your app.json file?

Comment: Thank you ! Of course but do you mean app.config.js ? I'm in Expo Bare workflow

Comment: Look at the manifest merger. You will find it there

Answer (score 0):

These permissions are written in the file `manifest.xml`

Comment: No presence of those permissions in there, that's why ...